# scalanlp breeze linear algebra: zip two vectors together

Tags: scala, scala-breeze, scala-nlp

I'm used to working with lists. If I have two lasts A and B and a function that takes two doubles and returns a double, then I could do the following

```
A.zip(B).map(x=>myfunction(x._1,x._2))
```

This is the way my brain is used to thinking about these problems.

Now that I am doing linear algebra with Breeze, A and B are both types DenseVector[Double], which have no zip method. Is there a good alternative of doing what I want to achieve?

Comment: did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912402/how-to-zip-two-densevectors-in-scala-breeze

Comment: I get the same missing parameter type error as in the link